# DocuSign : Add phone verification to envelope generated from a template

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am in the process of creating an integrated signature flow on our website via DocuSign PHP API.

I am trying to adapt this working example that create an envelope from a template located on my DocuSign account and populate the tabs with data from my session. This part is working.

I'm facing some difficulty to add phone verification according to :
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/phone-auth/

Now, I have set up a phone verification for the first signer on my template in my DocuSign account, and it seems something is wrong with my added code because, when I click on the button that generate the enveloppe, I'm stuck on the loading page of the https://verify-d.docusign.net/ChooseMethod url which is the URL where Docusign will make the phone authentication. I see an error 500 on this page, and the page is loading for infinite.

So, I guess there is something wrong with my work trying to add the phone verification to my function : So here is my EmbedSigningService.php :
(I have commented with "Elements added" so you can see my failed test)

```
<?php

namespace DocuSignSrc\Services;

use DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs;
use DocuSignSrc\Services\SignatureClientService;


use DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientIdentityVerification;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientPhoneNumber;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber;
use DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientIdentityInputOption;


class EmbeddedSigningService
{
    /**
     * Do the work of the example
     * 1. Create the envelope request object
     * 2. Send the envelope
     * 3. Create the Recipient View request object
     * 4. Obtain the recipient_view_url for the embedded signing
     *
     * @param  $args array
     * @param SignatureClientService $clientService
     * @return array ['redirect_url']
     */
    # ***DS.snippet.0.start
    public static function worker(array $args, SignatureClientService $clientService): array
    {
        # 1. Create the envelope request object
        $envelope_definition = EmbeddedSigningService::make_envelope($args["envelope_args"], $args["template_id"], $clientService);
        $envelope_api = $clientService->getEnvelopeApi();

        # 2. call Envelopes::create API method
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        try {
            $envelopeSummary = $envelope_api->createEnvelope($args['account_id'], $envelope_definition);
        } catch (ApiException $e) {
            $clientService->showErrorTemplate($e);
            exit;
        }
        $envelope_id = $envelopeSummary->getEnvelopeId();

        # 3. Create the Recipient View request object
        $authentication_method = 'None'; # How is this application authenticating
        # the signer? See the `authentication_method' definition
        # https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/
        $recipient_view_request = $clientService->getRecipientViewRequest(
            $authentication_method,
            $args["envelope_args"]
        );

        # 4. Obtain the recipient_view_url for the embedded signing
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        $viewUrl = $clientService->getRecipientView($args['account_id'], $envelope_id, $recipient_view_request);

        return ['envelope_id' => $envelope_id, 'redirect_url' => $viewUrl['url']];
    }

    /**
 *  Creates envelope definition
 *  Parameters for the envelope: signer_email, signer_name, signer_client_id
 *
 * @param  $args array
 * @param  $template_id string
 * @return EnvelopeDefinition -- returns an envelope definition
 */
public static function make_envelope(array $args, string $template_id, SignatureClientService $clientService): EnvelopeDefinition
{

    $accounts_api = $clientService->getAccountsApi();
        $accounts_response = $accounts_api->getAccountIdentityVerification($_SESSION['ds_account_id']);
        
        // *************** Elements added below
        $workflows_data = $accounts_response->getIdentityVerification();
        $workflow_id = '';
        foreach ($workflows_data as $workflow) {
            if ($workflow['default_name'] == 'Phone Authentication')
                $workflow_id = $workflow['workflow_id'];  
        }
        
        $phoneNumber = new RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber;
        $phoneNumber->setCountryCode($args['phone_country_code']);
        $phoneNumber->setNumber($args['phone_number']);

        $inputOption = new RecipientIdentityInputOption;
        $inputOption->setName('phone_number_list');
        $inputOption->setValueType('PhoneNumberList');
        $inputOption->setPhoneNumberList(array($phoneNumber));

        $identityVerification = new RecipientIdentityVerification;
        $identityVerification->setWorkflowId($workflow_id);
        $identityVerification->setInputOptions(array($inputOption));
        // ***************** End elements added


    $envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
        'status' => 'sent',
        'template_id' => $template_id,
        'template_roles' => [
            new TemplateRole([
                'email' => $args['signer_email'],
                'name' => $args['signer_name'],
                'role_name' => 'Client',
                'client_user_id' => $args['signer_client_id'],
                'tabs' => $args['tabs'],
                // ***************  ELement added below
                'identity_verification' => $identityVerification
             
            ])
        ]
    ]);

    return $envelope_definition;
}

    # ***DS.snippet.0.end
}
```

And here is my function that I call to generate all of this :

```
<?php 
function embedSigning()
{


    $signer_name = 'John Doe';
    $signer_email = 'my@email.com'; // Anonymated here
    $myphonenumber= '0000000'; //Anonymated for sharing here but format is correct
    $signer_client_id = 1000; # Used to indicate that the signer will use embedded
    $envelope_args = [
        'signer_email' => $signer_email,
        'signer_name' => $signer_name,
        'phone_number' => $myphonenumber,
        'phone_country_code' => '33',
        'signer_client_id' => $signer_client_id,
        'tabs' => [
            'textTabs' => [
                [
                    'tabLabel' => 'TAB_text_to_prefill', // Label de l'onglet dans le modèle
                    'value' => $_SESSION['My-prefill-session-content'], // Valeur à insérer dans l'onglet
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'ds_return_url' => $GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG']['app_url'] . '/process-signature.php?page=embed-signing-return',
        'template_id' => 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx', // Anonymated here for sharing
    ];

    $args = [
        'account_id' => $_SESSION['ds_account_id'],
        'base_path' => $_SESSION['ds_base_path'],
        'ds_access_token' => $_SESSION['ds_access_token'],
        'template_id' => 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx', // Spécifiez l'ID du modèle à utiliser
        'envelope_args' => $envelope_args
    ];

    $clientService = new SignatureClientService($args);


    $envelopeIdAndReturnUrl = EmbeddedSigningService::worker(
        $args,
        $clientService
    );
    if ($envelopeIdAndReturnUrl) {
        $_SESSION['envelope_id'] = $envelopeIdAndReturnUrl['envelope_id'];
        # Redirect the user to the embedded signing
        # Don't use an iFrame!
        # State can be stored/recovered using the framework's session or a
        # query parameter on the returnUrl (see the make recipient_view_request method)
        header('Location:' . $envelopeIdAndReturnUrl["redirect_url"]);
        exit();
    } else {
        die('$envelopeIdAndReturnUrl === false, censé ne jamais arriver');
    }
}
```

As you can see, I anonymized some variables, but without this adaptation to phone verification, everything works.

Thank you for your help !

#DocuSignAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the DocuSign support, so, for anyone who reach this question here is the answer : (+ You'll have more details on this blog post: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/using-identity-verification-templates )

**Unfortunately, it is not possible to send the phone authentication from a template within template roles**. A workaround for this issue
is:

1. create a draft from a template

POST {baseUrl}/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

```
{
  "templateId": "[TEMPLATE ID]",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "[RECIPEITN EMAIL]",
      "name": "[RECIPEITN NAME]",
      "roleName": "[ROLE NAME]"
    }
  ],
  "status": "created"
}
```

2. Get the phone authentication workflow ID (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/identityverifications/list/)

GET {baseUrl}/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/identity_verification

3. and then update the recipient with the identityVerification information (updateRecipients API:
   https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/update/)

PUT
{baseUrl}/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "recipientId": "[RECIPEITN ID]",
      "identityVerification": {
        "workflowId": "[Workflow ID retrievd from step2]",
        "steps": null,
        "inputOptions": [
          {
            "name": "phone_number_list",
            "valueType": "PhoneNumberList",
            "phoneNumberList": [
              {
                "countryCode": "[COUNTRY CODE]",
                "number": "[PHONE NUMBER]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

4. Send the envelope with the updateEnvelopes API(https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/update/)

PUT {baseUrl}/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}

```
{"status": "sent"}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are running this on your demo account. Demo accounts do not have Phone Authentication enabled by default, if you are unable to see the options via the Web UI and set it up there when you try to create an envelope, then it might not be enabled for your demo account. In which case you would need to reach out to DocuSign Customer Support to have this enabled.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. This is active as I am able to generate an enveloppe from the UI with this phone verification + the option is added to my template + I see it in the ID check settings as "Phone Authentication"

So, this is why my guess leads me to my code which is maybe not implemented in the right way ?